# Include LaTeX file named with substring of current filename

Tags: strings, text-manipulation

I'm frequently creating presentations with beamer and need both the handout and the presentation itself. To avoid editing the file when I need to compile the other, I use `\ifdefined\ishandout ...` at the beginning of the presentation and have a separate file for the handout that contains nothing but

```
\def\ishandout{1}
\input{topic.tex}
```

Since the handout file is always named following the schema `topic_handout.tex` I'm looking for a way to strip the inner `_handout` so I can use the same handout file for all presentations without changing the content. I found `\jobname` which gives me `topic_handout`, so I just need to strip the constant string `_handout` and add `.tex` to the argument in `\input`. Since this happens before the document class is declared, I cannot use any packages. Any help is welcome.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please use backticks `\`` to mark inline code, file names etc.

Comment: You actually can use packages before `\documentclass` by using `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`. But you should be careful anyway. Also you can use `\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}` and `\mode<handout>{...}` instead of `\def\ishandout{1}` and `\ifdefined\ishandout ...`, respectively. Note that `\jobname` returns the file name as *characters* (catcode 12, "other") and not as *letters* (catcode 11), which must be taken into account for string comparison and manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, will use the backticks in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clear what the problem is; as I have understood it, you want that

```
pdflatex topic_handout
```

actually inputs `topic.tex` after defining `\ishandout`. This can be done all on the command line, without an auxiliary file `topic_handout.tex`:

```
pdflatex "\def\ishandout{1}\input{topic}"
```

If you don't want to use the command line, your `topic_handout.tex` file may be

```
\def\ishandout{1}

\edef\x{\def\noexpand\dehandout##1\detokenize{_handout}{##1}}\x
\expandafter\input\expandafter{\expandafter\dehandout\jobname}
```

Comment: +1, using `\detokenize` instead of `\@onelevel@sanitize` is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a macro with `_handout` in the parameter text, so that this part is then removed. This requires a little more advanced coding. Here my try to explain it:

You need to use the plainTeX macro `\def` instead of LaTeX's `\newcommand` for this.  One issue is that all characters except spaces in `\jobname` are returned with catcode 12 *other* and are not *letters* (catcode 11) as normal. To define a macro with the correct catcodes you can use e.g. LaTeX's `\@onelevel@sanitize` macro to turn the whole macro definition to catcode *other*. Then you need a lot of `\expandafter`s to expand the helper macro before the removal macro is defined.

```
% somename_handout.tex
\def\handoutstr{_handout}
\makeatletter
\@onelevel@sanitize\handoutstr% to get right catcodes!
\makeatother
\expandafter\def\expandafter\removehandout\expandafter#\expandafter1\handoutstr\relax{#1}

%\def\ishandout{1}
% better:
\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}

\input{\expandafter\removehandout\jobname\relax}
```

In addition it is better to use `\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}` instead of `\def\ishandout{1}`. This passes the `handout` option directly to the `beamer` class. Then in the presentation file you can use `\mode<handout>{ handout-only code }`:

```
% somename.tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<handout>{%
  % handout-only code
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 % ...
\end{frame}

% ...
%
\end{document}
```