# Parsing file name into document

Tags: parsing

I have a group of tex files named according to the following convention:

xxx_yyy_zzz.tex

I would like to use the components (xxx, yyy, zzz) of the file name as inputs in the document, n particular when creating the title / header. For example, I would like to be able to set the title of the document to be `Learning about yyy'' and the author to be`zzz'' with a footer that says xxx.

I have so far found some code that lets me remove the end of a file name: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21808

I have also tried using \StrBetween from the xstring package to process \currfilename from the currfile package, but this doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\filename@parse{\currfilename}
\StrBetween{\filename@base}{_}{_}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Actually I think I'm using \StrBetween wrong, but even if I do something like

```
\StrBetween{\filename@base}{xxx}{zzz}
```

it doesn't print out yyy, but if I do

```
\StrBetween{a \filename@base b}{a}{b}
```

then it will print xxx_yyy_zzz.

Are there any suggestions as to how I can take a file named xxx_yyy_zzz.tex and include the text components xxx, yyy, and zzz to be used later in the file, e.g., in the header or title?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a very specific filename-pattern, you can use TeX's `\def` to define a specific parameter text, from which you can extract the elements of the filename within the argument text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\_=12
\newcommand{\filenameparse}[1]{\expandafter\filename@parse@#1\@nil}
\def\filename@parse@#1_#2_#3\@nil{%
  \gdef\fileA{#1}% first part
  \gdef\fileB{#2}% middle part
  \gdef\fileC{#3}% final part
}
\catcode`\_=8
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\filenameparse{\jobname}

\verb|\fileA:| \fileA \par
\verb|\fileB:| \fileB \par
\verb|\fileC:| \fileC
\end{document}
```

`\jobname` carries the name of the file (without extension), which is then processed as `#1_#2_#3`, each component of which is extracted as `\fileA`, `\fileB` and `\fileC`, respectively.

Comment: [I tried something similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339786). The `catcode` of `_` must be `12` for this to work. I have submitted an edit, in case you want to add the two required lines.

Answer (score 2):

Werner's solution is the better way to parse the separate componets in this case, but here is a method that uses the [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/)' macros `\StrBefore`, and `\StrBetween` to extract the relevant components.

With the file below named `"theory-relaivity-Einstein.tex"`, this outputs:

[image]

### Code:

```
% This file is called "theory-relaivity-Einstein.tex"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

% Ensure that we are no overriding any existing macros:
\newcommand*{\XXX}{}%
\newcommand*{\YYY}{}%
\newcommand*{\ZZZ}{}%

\newcommand*{\FileNameParse}{%
    \StrBefore{\currfilename}{-}[\XXX]%
    \StrBetween[1,2]{\currfilename}{-}{-}[\YYY]%
    \StrBetween[2,1]{\currfilename}{-}{.}[\ZZZ]%
}%



\begin{document}
\FileNameParse
XXX=\XXX,

Learning about ``\YYY"
Author=``\ZZZ".

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This implements a fairly general splitting method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nV }
\seq_new:N \l_liz_jobname_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitjobname}{m}
 {
  \regex_split:nVN { #1 } \c_sys_jobname_str \l_liz_jobname_seq
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\jobnamepart}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \l_liz_jobname_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\splitjobname{ _ }

\begin{document}

First part: \jobnamepart{1}\par
Second part: \jobnamepart{2}\par
Third part: \jobnamepart{3}

\end{document}
```

If the job name is `xxx_yyy_zzz.tex`, then the output will be

[image]

If the job name is `xxx-yyy_zzz.tex`, then with

```
\splitjobname{ [ _ \- ] }
```

one would get the same output.