# Generalized File Name Parsing

Tags: parsing, jobname

In [Parse filename and extract revision from name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272207/89497), the OP wanted to parse a file name of the format cv3.01 to extract the revision number 3.01.

@egreg posted the following solution for a file name with a general prefix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\edef\revision@prefix{\detokenize{%
  % customize based on the file name structure
  cv% <---- change the characters before %
}}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\revision@get\revision@prefix#1\@nil{#1}
\edef\revision{\expandafter\revision@get\jobname\@nil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This document is Rev~\revision.

\end{document}
```

What if I had a file name structure like cv3.01temp? How could this approach be generalized to parse the file name as given by `\jobname` with an arbitrary (potentially empty) prefix and postfix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the file as `cv3.01temp.tex` and enjoy. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\edef\revision@prefix{\detokenize{%
  % customize based on the file name structure
  cv% <---- change the characters before %
}}
\edef\revision@postfix{\detokenize{%
  % customize based on the file name structure
  temp% <---- change the characters before %
}}
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand\revision@get\revision@prefix##1\revision@postfix\noexpand\@nil{##1}}%
\x
\edef\revision{\expandafter\revision@get\jobname\@nil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This document is Rev~\revision.

\end{document}
```

The `\@nil` has been kept in case the postfix is empty.

---

The trick is, besides detokenizing the prefix and postfix for the already explained reason, to define `\revision@get` so that it has a single argument delimited by the (detokenized) prefix and the (detokenized) postfix followed by `\@nil`. This is achieved by expanding the strings inside an `\edef` and then executing the obtained macro.

Actually an argument delimiter is only what follows the parameter in the `<parameter text>`, so the leading tokens are just required after the macro name.

---

Just for fun, here's a way to extract the first run of digits and periods from the job name; if no such run is found, `\revision` is set to `???`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_once:nnNTF { nV }
\regex_extract_once:nVNTF { [\d\.]+ } \c_sys_jobname_str \l_tmpa_seq
 { \tl_set:Nx \revision { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } } }
 { \tl_set:Nn \revision { ??? } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This document is Rev~\revision.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` pair required? I've pulled it out and its seems to work fine.

Comment: @Guho They're for removing the definition of `\x` when it's executed.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose you would only want to be able to execute it once. Stellar answer!

Comment: @Guho Yes, `\x` is executed once and then undefined; or it reverts to the previous definition if there was one. Covering one's tracks. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zzz{\expandafter\zzzz\filename\relax}
\def\zzzz#1{%
\ifcat1#1#1\fi
\ifx\relax#1\else\expandafter\zzzz\fi}

\begin{document}

\def\filename{cv3.01temp} Revision: \zzz

\def\filename{3.02temp} Revision: \zzz

\def\filename{cv3.03} Revision: \zzz

\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter
\edef\expandafter\filename\expandafter{\jobname}}
Revision: \zzz


\end{document}
```

Comment: My intention was for the file name to be defined automatically from `\jobname`.  I have clarified the question.

Comment: @Guho ah now that's unfortunate as `\jobname` is a rather special beast, any "letters" are not letters (catcode 11) but all catcode 12, so the above test won't distinguish letters from numbers in `\jobname`, i'll add a wrapper to so `\jobname` works in a minute...

Comment: @Guho updated answer showing you get `5` if `\jobname` is `foo5zzz`

Comment: What if the file name is `cv3.01-temp`?

Comment: @egreg then you get the answer you expect.

Comment: The question was about *arbitrary* prefix and postfix.

Comment: @egeg if needed you could locally make - catcode 11, it covers more cases than just looking for a fixed string `temp% <---- change the characters before %` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using a `listofitems` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\revision[1]{
  \setsepchar{cv||temp}%
  \ignoreemptyitems
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \mylist[1]%
}
\begin{document}
\revision{cv3.01temp}

\revision{3.02temp}

\revision{cv3.03}

\def\filename{cv3.04atemp2017-10-27}
\revision{\filename}
\end{document}
```

[image]