# Command receiving multiple parameters in one string fails when passed parameters are in a variable

Tags: macros

I tried to use what was explained [in this Tex SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19693/arguments-of-custom-commands-as-comma-separated-list/19698#19698) to set three variables from a string separated by hyphens:

```
\def\parsevars#1{\parsehelper(#1)}
\def\parsehelper(#1-#2-#3) {\def\varone{#1} \def\vartwo{#2} \def\varthree{#3}}
```

Then, I want to use these variables in my document. This works wonderfully:

```
\parsevars{Jake-Jane-Jerry}
When \varone entered the room, \vartwo was in awful shock. \varone was wearing \varthree's clothes!
```

However, if the string is in a variable, it doesn't work:

```
\newcommand{\myvar}{Jake-Jane-Jerry}
\parsevars{\myvar}
```

More specifically, I am trying to parse the `\jobname` variable:

```
\parsevars{\jobname}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need [`\expandafter`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/docsvlist.shtml#gls:expandafter1) This could go inside the definition of `\def\parsevars#1{\expandafter\parsehelper\expandafter(#1)}`.

Comment: I forgot to add, Welcome to TeX.SX! :-)

Comment: Maybe you can look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153769/parsing-file-name-into-document

Comment: Also, don't forget that you have a *probably unintended* extra space in the definition of `\parsehelper` before the brace: `) {` should be `){`.

Comment: How to treat filemames/\jobnames with closing parenteses somewhere behind the second hyphen ? Filenames and thus `\jobname`-expansions like `CategoryA-CategoryB-CategoryC(SubCategoryC)SomeMoreCharacters` are possible with nowadays' file-systems.  `\parsevar/\parsehelper` would split this to `\varone`-> `CategoryA` and `\vartwo`-> `CategoryB` and `\varthree->`CategoryC(SubCategoryC` and a remainder `SomeMoreCharacters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting my comment into an answer.) The argument needs to be expanded before being parsed. This can be done in the definition of `\parsevars`:

```
\def\parsevars#1{\expandafter\parsehelper\expandafter(#1)}

\parsevars{\myvar}
\parsevars{\jobname}
```

or just when using `\parsevars`:

```
\expandafter\parsevars\expandafter{\myvar}
\expandafter\parsevars\expandafter{\jobname}
```

[More information on `\expandafter`.](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/docsvlist.shtml#gls:expandafter1)

*Edit:* regarding your comment about `xstring`, I'm guessing you've tried to parse `\jobname` and then used something like `\IfStrEq`. (If I'm wrong, you'll need to edit your question so that it has a minimal working example.)

The problem is most likely due to the fact that all the characters `a`, `b`, etc in `\jobname` are given a [category code](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/glossary.shtml#gls:catcode) of 12 ("other") instead of their usual 11 ("letter"). We can simulate a command that replicates this behaviour using:

```
\edef\testjobname{\detokenize{Jake-Jane-Jerry}}
```

This is just for testing purposes to illustrate the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

% simulate \jobname:
\edef\testjobname{\detokenize{Jake-Jane-Jerry}}

\newcommand{\myvar}{Jake-Jane-Jerry}

\def\parsevars#1{\expandafter\parsehelper\expandafter(#1)}
\def\parsehelper(#1-#2-#3){\def\varone{#1}\def\vartwo{#2}\def\varthree{#3}}

\begin{document}
\parsevars{\myvar}

Testing \varone: \IfStrEq{\varone}{Jake}{True}{False}.

\parsevars{\testjobname}

Testing \varone: \IfStrEq{\varone}{Jake}{True}{False}.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Testing Jake: True. Testing Jake: False.]

In both cases `\varone` has the definition `Jake`, but in the first case these four letters have category code 11 (which matches the string `Jake`) whereas in the second case they have category code 12 (which doesn't match).

In this case you're better off using `etoolbox` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% simulate \jobname:
\edef\testjobname{\detokenize{Jake-Jane-Jerry}}

\newcommand{\myvar}{Jake-Jane-Jerry}

\def\parsevars#1{\expandafter\parsehelper\expandafter(#1)}
\def\parsehelper(#1-#2-#3){\def\varone{#1}\def\vartwo{#2}\def\varthree{#3}}

\begin{document}
\parsevars{\myvar}

Testing \varone: \ifdefstring{\varone}{Jake}{True}{False}.

\parsevars{\testjobname}

Testing \varone: \ifdefstring{\varone}{Jake}{True}{False}.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Testing Jake: True. Testing Jake: True.]

If you want some other comparison, you'll need to add some example code.

Comment: Thanks Nicola! For some reason when I try to compare any of the `\varone`, `vartwo` etc. with `xstring.sty`, it always returns false. Could this also be related to `\expandafter`?

Comment: @Lesik2008 It sounds more like it's related to the category code used in `\jobname`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A different implementation with `expl3`; the file was named `Jake-Jane-Jerry.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Access the various parts
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\jobnamepart}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_lesik_jobname_parts_seq { #1 }
 }
% Initialize
\seq_new:N \g_lesik_jobname_parts_seq
\seq_gset_split:NnV \g_lesik_jobname_parts_seq { - } \c_sys_jobname_str
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

When \jobnamepart{1} entered the room, \jobnamepart{2} was in awful 
shock. \jobnamepart{1} was wearing \jobnamepart{3}'s clothes!

\end{document}
```

[image]